# How to properly run SQL extensions thru Saxon in Oxygen

Tags: xml, xslt, saxon, oxygenxml

I am trying to test usage of the sql extensions of Saxon EE thru Oxygen. I am getting an error that the driver failed to load:

**Engine name: Saxon-EE 11.4

Severity: fatal

Problem ID: SXSQ0003

Description: Failed to load JDBC driver org.sqlite.JDBC

Start location: 30:106

URL: http://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation/javadoc/net/sf/saxon/trans/SaxonErrorCode.html#SXSQ0003**

This is my XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:sql="http://saxon.sf.net/sql"
    xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net/"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="3.0">
    
    <xsl:param name="user"/>
    <xsl:param name="password"/>
    
    <xsl:variable name="driver" select="'org.sqlite.JDBC'"/>
    <xsl:variable name="database" select="'jdbc:sqlite:S1000D.db'"/>
    
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <test-output>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </test-output>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="xref">
        <xsl:variable name="xrefid" select="@xrefid"/>
        <xsl:if test="not(element-available('sql:connect'))">
            <xsl:message terminate="yes">sql:connect not available</xsl:message>
        </xsl:if>
        
        <xsl:message>Connecting to <xsl:value-of select="$database"/>...</xsl:message>
        
        <xsl:variable name="conn" as="java:java.sql.Connection" xmlns:java="http://saxon.sf.net/java-type">
            <sql:connect driver="{$driver}" database="{$database}" user="{$user}" password="{$password}">
                <xsl:fallback>
                    <xsl:message terminate="yes">SQL Extensions are not installed</xsl:message>
                </xsl:fallback>
                <xsl:message>Connected...</xsl:message>
            </sql:connect>
        </xsl:variable>
        
        <xsl:variable name="q">
            <sql:query connection="$conn" table="'DataModule'" column="'*'" where="'LmTask_ID = {$xrefid}'"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        
        <xsl:for-each select="$q">
            <dmRef>
                <dmcode>
                    <!-- Use values from the query to populate the dmcode attributes -->
                </dmcode>
            </dmRef>
        </xsl:for-each>
        
    </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is the SaxonEE config file in our project:

```
<configuration edition="EE" xmlns="http://saxon.sf.net/ns/configuration" label="Saxon-EE (no threads)">
    <global allowMultiThreading="false" 
        timing="true" 
        validationWarnings="true" 
        validationComments="true" 
        allowExternalFunctions="true" 
        compileWithTracing="false" 
        lineNumbering="true" 
        traceExternalFunctions="true" 
        expandAttributeDefaults="true" 
        allowSyntaxExtensions="true"/>
    <xslt>
        <extensionElement namespace="http://saxon.sf.net/sql" factory="net.sf.saxon.option.sql.SQLElementFactory"/>
    </xslt>
</configuration>
```

I tried to copy the latest SQLite driver jar (sqlite-jdbc-3.42.0.0.jar) to the Oxygen lib folder and it complained. I them moved it to the lib/connectors folder. It has not complained about it being located there but also still fails. I am not sure where to locate the jar in order for Saxon to load the JDBC.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: It might be better to add a tag for Oxygen or to ask their support. Anyway, I would also try, in the XSLT transformation scenario, where you can provide extension libs for Saxon, to list the jdbc sql lite driver there, perhaps Saxon then picks it up.

Comment: I had Oxygen tagged, but it said I do not have enough reputation or something to create a new tag. Maybe I just had it mispelled?

Comment: See following : https://github.com/xerial/sqlite-jdbc#usage

Comment: @MartinHonnen I added the jar to the extension libraries but had no change in output.

Comment: @DanielHaley funny guy, :)

Comment: Let's wait for oXygen support to pick that up, I don't know where to put the sqlite jar for Saxon to pick it up when used in an oXygen transformation scenario; when I run Saxon EE from the java command line directly it works for me to add it in the `-cp` option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation https://www.oxygenxml.com/doc/versions/25.1/ug-editor/topics/application-reports-errors-on-startup.html suggests, to allow you to add e.g. `sqlite-jdbc-3.42.0.0.jar` to Oxygen XML's lib folder and to not have it complain, you can put the file in the folder and edit the file `libraries.list` in there to add e.g. `;sqlite-jdbc-3.42.0.0.jar` at the end of the list. I have tested that oXygen then runs Saxon EE 11 successfully doing an sqlite connection with the sql extension elements. Note that while I put the jar in the lib folder and edited the `libaries.list` I had oXygen closed and then restarted it for the changes to take effect.

Nevertheless, wait for the oXygen support to tell what they consider the easiest/straight-forward way to have Saxon pick up the sqlite jdbc driver for an XSLT scenario.